# OpenGL behaves differently in ubuntu and windows

Tags: opengl, opengl-compat

I am using wxGLContext and wxGLCanvas for 3D visualization. I initialized opengl like this

```
SetCurrent(*canvas);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
```

and draw the objects

```
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-w, w, -h, h, -10.0f, 10.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
quad = gluNewQuadric();
glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
//draw the objects
gluDeleteQuadric(quad);
glFlush();
```

The problem is that this code works fine in windows, but in ubuntu the objects clipped by the objects which are located in back. The glFrontFace is correct for all objects, but clipping is wrong.

Comment: Maybe you get a context without a depth buffer? `wxGLContext` probably has a way to explicitly request a depth buffer when creating a context.

Comment: You are very smart. Thank you a lot. I used  this attribute int AttribList[] = {WX_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, WX_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16, 0};

Comment: I suggest posting it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **HolyBlackCat** mentioned in the comments,
the problem was depth buffer for the wxGLContext.
It works by using WX_GL_DEPTH_SIZE 8 and 16, but not 32.

Although, I still do not know, how windows can handle it without error, I corrected some lines as follows

```
int AttribList[] = {WX_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, WX_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16, 0};
wxGLCanvas* glc = new wxGLCanvas(parent, wxID_ANY, AttribList,
                                 wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize,
                                 wxFULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE);
```

and now it works for both OSs.